# Frequency Count of Number in an array in C is this code effective and efficient

Tags: c, arrays, frequency

I have the following code in c for counting frequency of number from array:

```
#define MAX 10
int flag=0;

void display(int no,int cnt,int visi[]);//function declaration 

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,1,1,2,3,4,2,2,3,1};//asume any array or we can enter from user
    int visited[MAX];
    int i,j,no,cnt=1;
    clrscr();
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)//loop
    {
        no=arr[i];
        cnt=1;
        for(j=i+1;j<10;j++)
        {
            if(no==arr[j])
                cnt++;
        }
        display(no,cnt,visited);
    }
    return 0;
}

void display(int no,int cnt,int visited[])
{
  int static i;
  int j;

  if(flag==1)
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
    {
      if(visited[j]==no)
        goto a;
    }
  i++;
  flag=1;
  printf("\n%d=%d",no,cnt);
  visited[i]=no;
  a:
}
```

Please help to improve my code or suggest any other technology for effectiveness
is this algorithm effective and efficient or not please give feedback.

Comment: the label at the end of the function is a compile time error. `void main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: A. Some Cr issues (define `MAX` and then use `10` - why?) B. You are doing `O(n^2)` - which is the worst you can do (though sometimes that is necessary).

Comment: Do you know anything in advance about the range of the numbers in the array? Knowing this can dramatically improve your efficiency (again, only sometimes)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Providing more context would probably improve how people can help you. What type of ineffectivity / inefficiency do you face?

Comment: @M Oehm thanks for feedback can give me any example how to do that??

Comment: @shapiroyaacov thanks range of array can be anything we can set array size max and get input from users till n elements

Comment: One idea - sort the array `O(n log n)` and then go over it once - that's already an improvement...

Comment: @shapiroyaacov ohh yeah you are right sorting also can solve problem thank you!! :)

Comment: Well isn't this here offtopic? Stackoverflow ontopic rules say you need a specific problem you can specify. But the request for reviewing code would better fit to CodeReview exchange, wouldn't it?

Comment: "The principal difference between Code Review and Stack Overflow is that the former is for reviews of code that *already works as intended* whereas Stack Overflow is all about code that doesn't work." ([source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275116/2564301))

Answer (score 2):

to count frequency of numbers in array, try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int countArray[MAX];

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,1,1,2,3,4,2,2,3,1},i;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
         countArray[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
        countArray[arr[i]]++;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        if(countArray[i])
            printf("%d %d\n",i,countArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the values in the array can be anything. `countArray[1000]` is gonna give you some interesting times...

Comment: Check now. @shapiroyaacov . Thanks

Comment: `countArray` is of size 10. if the `arr` is `{100,123,135}` what do you think will happes when you try `countArray[arr[i]]++;` ?

Comment: That's a sample code. You can update this code depends on your requirements. @shapiroyaacov

Comment: I'll try and explain my point once more: if the values in the input array are not limited, then the size of `countArray` must be the biggest number possible in order for this to work. This means that this solution is very problematic, especially if you input is a `long long int`. If the question stated that the input values were bound by lets say 100, then you solution would be great - please see the third comment to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the array first by merge sort (`O(n log n)`) and then calculate the frequency of a number by single loop like this-:

```
int j=0;    
for( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
{    
    if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) 
        cnt++;
    else 
    {
        visited[j] = cnt; 
        cnt = 0;
        j++;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say this explicitly, but it looks as if you had an array of non-negative numbers whsoe values is smaller than `MAX`.

If the range of the numbers is known, you can create an array of counts. Visit each element of the array once and increment the count for that element. Then pass through the array of counts and output it as appropriate.

This method works well if the range of valid numbers and therefore the size of the `count` array is small. (You have the same problem for your `visited` array, whose size is the same as the size of an array of counts.)

The example below implements counting with an array of counts. The code also takes care of values that fall outside the valid range of `MIN` to `MAX` inclusively.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN 1
#define MAX 10

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3};
    int narr = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    int count[MAX + 1 - MIN] = {0};
    int uncounted = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < narr; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < MIN || arr[i] > MAX) {
            uncounted++;
        } else {
            count[arr[i] - MIN]++;
        }
    }

    for(i = MIN; i < MAX + 1; i++) {
        if (count[i - MIN]) {
            printf("element %d ocurs %d times.\n", i, count[i - MIN]);
        }
    }

    if (uncounted) {
        printf("%d elements were not accounted for.\n",  uncounted);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
```

Is implementation dependant. You do not wan't to use this, some compilers will not accept it.

Use

```
int main(void)
```

instead

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)//loop
```

You already defined `MAX`, so why not use it there. Stuff like this makes code harder to maintain.

The efficiency is dependant on the input values you have. For small arrays with small numbers, this works fine otherwise.

Comment: thank you for suggestion i was in so hurry while doing that program i forgot about MAX but now i understand my mistake ...