# How to count occurrences with 'Divide and Conquer' method

Tags: arrays, algorithm, find-occurrences

I'm looking for an algorithm to count the number of occurrences of each element in an array, using the Divide and Conquer method.

Here's an example;

```
Input: 12-3-5-3-12-3
OutPut: (12, 2), (3, 3), (5,1)
```

Can anyone at least give me an idea where to start?
Thank you

Comment: You can start with: https://www.google.ro/search?q=Divide+and+Conquer

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I did that, and I've done so many reseaches, and I understand the devide and conquer method nicely, but still... I can't find the way to solve the problem.

Comment: You probably need a handle on a global data structure that manages the occurrences (possibly a balanced tree) that you pass around. What's left is recursive bisection of the input array. Am I missing something from your specs?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and work on the balanced tree idea. I'll let you guys what happens.

Comment: I'm not sure using a tree would count as using a divide and conquer algorithm. I didn't advise heap sorting + counting for this reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473716/frequency-count-of-number-in-an-array-in-c-is-this-code-effective-and-efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) the array and then output the values with their count in a single pass of the sorted array.

Alternatively, you could also map your input array to an array of pairs: `(number, 1)`. Then divide and conquer as in the [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), but in the merge phase, you increment the count of the same numbers instead of outputting it multiple times.

Example code in python

```
#!python

input = [12, 3, 5, 3, 12, 3];

def count_occurrences(input):
    """ Divide """
    if(len(input) == 0):
        return []
    if(len(input) == 1):
        return [(input[0], 1)]
    left   = count_occurrences(input[:len(input)/2])
    right  = count_occurrences(input[len(input)/2:])

    """ Conquer """
    result = []
    i=0
    j=0
    imax=len(left)
    jmax=len(right)
    while(i<imax and j<jmax):
        if(left[i][0] < right[j][0]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i = i+1
        elif(left[i][0] > right[j][0]):
            result.append(right[j])
            j = j+1
        else:
            result.append((left[i][0], left[i][1]+right[j][1]))
            i = i+1
            j = j+1
    while(i<imax):
        result.append(left[i])
        i = i+1;
    while(j<jmax):
        result.append(right[j])
        j = j+1;

    return result


print (count_occurrences(input))
```

This will print:

```
$ python how-to-count-occurrences-with-divide-and-conquer-method.py
[(3, 3), (5, 1), (12, 2)]
```